# MATLAB include error : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cblas.h'

Tags: matlab, include-path

I am using a optimization toolbox for solving sparse estimation problems. I have downloaded the software from [SPAMS homepage](http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/index.html)  and would like to create a mex-file from mexLasso.m for my application.

I transfer all the error-invoking include files to MATLAB external/include folder. In MATLAB, once I type in:

```
>> mex mexLasso.cpp
```

I receive this error:

> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include\utils.h(28)
>         fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cblas.h'

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For mex-ing:  Have you setup your compiler?

```
>> mex -setup
```

Choose visual studio compiler over Matlab's `lcc`.

Do you have a header file `cblas.h`? where is it located?

Use the following flags to compile

```
>> mex -O -largeArrayDims -v mexLasso.cpp
```

The `-v` flag should give you a verbose output - see what are the include directories the compiler search in for header file. You can add folders to the search path with the flag `-I <folder name>`